# How to get an application's all processes in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get the processes information of **Microsoft 365**' in C# code.

[image]

I try to use the Process.GetProcesses() but it return all the processes runnung on my PC.  I only want the related 8 processes. How should I do it?

Comment: @shingo  I try the Process.GetProcessesByName("Microsoft 365") but it retun null

Comment: @ATAO Are you sure "Microsoft 365" is the full name? shouldn't it be "Microsoft 365 (office) app"

Comment: @ATAO Name is the name of the executable file without the .exe extension.

Comment: @shingoI try the executable exe file which is webviewhost.exe and run Process.GetProcessesByName("webviewhost") , this only return only 1 process and can't  get ohter webview2 prcesses.

Comment: Rather look at the details page of the taskmanager to find the "real" names for processes. If you need the process structure at the same time you may want to look at alternative Taskmanagers like Sysinternals Process Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

As far i know microsoft 365 location is very hard to find as it seems to be a web app judging that the process name looks to be WebViewHost.exe so it may not return the result expected but if you want to try anyway you can do:
Process.GetProcessesByName("WebViewHost")

Comment: This Process.GetProcessesByName("WebViewHost") only return 1 process. Can't return the webview2 processes.